# Should I use a closure instead of a class when I only have one method?

Tags: javascript, class, closures

Lets say I have a JavaScript class that takes a whole lot of settings in the constructor, and then only have one method that the user of the class might want to call multiple times. Here's an example:

```
class Doer {

    constructor(settings) {
        this._settings = settings;
    }

    function doIt(params) {
        //Return something based on this._settings and params.
    }

}

let myDoer = new Doer(mySettings);
myDoer.doIt(params);
```

An alternative approach would be to use a closure:

```
function createDoer(settings) {
    return function doIt(params) {
        // Return something based on settings and params.
    }
}

let myDoer = createDoer(mySettings);
myDoer(myParams);
```

What are the pros and cons of these two different ways of doing it? When should I use a class, and when should I use a closure?

On one hand, using a class seems like overly relying on OOP when a simple functional concept is enough. But on the other hand, the class is more extensible in case the needs of the project would change.

Comment: They are not interchangeable. E.g. you can't pass your class to `map` or `fold`

Comment: First: Classes are only syntactic sugar for closures. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/classes That said, it is up to you and to your taste in this case, what _feels_ better.

Comment: Why do people never think they can switch to a class later "in case the needs of the project would change?"